# How does Mongoengine decide if 2 EmbeddedDocuments are equal or not?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following Mongoengine document:

```
class MyEmbed(EmbeddedDocument):
    embedField = StringField(primary_key=True)
    varField = StringField()

class TestDoc(Document):
    myField = StringField()
    embed_list = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(MyEmbed))
```

So I keep a list of embedded documents, to which I wish to add new documents if they don't exist already. The problem is that when I use the atomic update operator **add_to_set** things don't turn out the way I want them to. 
This is what I am trying to do:

```
embed1 = models.MyEmbed(embedField="F1")
parent = models.TestDoc(myField="ParentField")
embed_list = []
embed_list.append(embed1)
parent.embed_list = embed_list
parent.save()

embed2 = models.MyEmbed(embedField="F1", varField="varField")
TestDoc.objects(id=parent.id).update_one(add_to_set__embed_list=embed2)
```

The problem is that after doing this, I have in the DB a list of embedded documents with 2 elements. And what I want is to decide upon one field  (embedField in this case) whether 2 EmbeddedDocuments are equal or not, and not by taking into account all the properties. My questions are:

- What are the default criteria according to which Mongoengine decides whether 2 EmbeddedDocuments are equal or not?
- How can I redefine the function that makes Mongoengine decide when 2 EmbeddedDocuments are equal or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual checking is done inside MongoDB and **not** mongoengine.

The object sent to mongodb should be the same, but this is where it gets tricky as with BSON order is important and in python with dictionaries its not.  When converting to send to mongodb mongoengine just passes a dictionary.  This is a bug - so I've added [#296](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/296) and will fix for 0.8

Comment: I see.Thanks for the explanation. Then I am really looking forward for 0.8...:D

Answer (score -1):

See https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/document.py#L51 and https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/base/document.py#L52:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return self._data == other._data
    return False
```

It compare dicts of Embedded documents data. So you can override this method.

If you look at Document update that calls QuerySet update (find `add_to_set` and `addToSet`) you can find that mongoengine doesnt't check exists document in list and just call [mongo $addToSet operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/): https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/queryset/transform.py#L156.

In your code you have document `MyEmbed(embedField="F1")` and try add another document `MyEmbed(embedField="F1", varField="varField")` so logic right: it add new document. If you try next code:

```
embed1 = models.MyEmbed(embedField="F1")
parent = models.TestDoc(myField="ParentField")
embed_list = []
embed_list.append(embed1)
parent.embed_list = embed_list
parent.save()

embed2 = models.MyEmbed(embedField="F1", varField="varField")
TestDoc.objects(id=parent.id).update_one(add_to_set__embed_list=embed2)

embed3 = models.MyEmbed(embedField="F1")
TestDoc.objects(id=parent.id).update_one(add_to_set__embed_list=embed3)

embed4 = models.MyEmbed(embedField="F1", varField="varField")
TestDoc.objects(id=parent.id).update_one(add_to_set__embed_list=embed4)
```

you can find that parent contains only `embed1` and `embed2`.

So, to resolve you problem you can override `__eq__` method and check document in list, but you must find another solution for update document list, because it have direct call of mongo method.

Comment: Its true it uses __eq__ for local comparisons but not for the query as shown as that is done inside MongoDB.